# Why isn't the Python debugger working in VS Code?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have the Python extension installed in VS Code, but whenever I set a breakpoint in my program and run the debugger, it just seems to run the whole program and exit. It doesn't stop or enter any kind of debugging stage. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: Node.js file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit 2: Sample program

```
import string
import random

class Robot:
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    numbers = string.digits

    def __init__(self):
        random.seed()
        self.name = self.generate_name()

    def generate_name(self):
        return ''.join(random.choices(Robot.letters, k=2)) + ''.join(random.choices(Robot.numbers, k=3))

    def reset(self):
        self.__init__()
```

Comment: Did you fix the problem? It could be for many reasons. It will be helpful if you share launch.json and main.py file.

Comment: No, it still just runs through the program. The only launch.json file I have is whatever came with VS Code. I haven't changed any of that, but I have the Python extension installed, so I thought it should just work. I'll edit my post to include the Node.js file that I found.

Comment: Is it possible to share your python code and show on which line you are trying to put a breakpoint?

Comment: Oh sure, sorry about that! I'll add the code to a random program I'm doing, but I've tried it with many different little programs like this and it never works. On this particular one I put the breakpoint at line 10, if that matters.

Comment: @JohnSalerno still not sure how you starting your debugging session. anyway, "program": "${file}" in the node.js means you have to select your main or starting python file and then press the debug button.

Comment: To debug, I use the Debug icon on the left side panel, and then that brings up the Debugging panel. From there I just click "Run and Debug Python," which brings up a dropdown box called "Select a debug configuration." From that list I choose "Python file."